# Change state in an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, state

When I click on the element, it changes to "pressed" (i see that while inspecting) but it doesn't take what `.pressed` has inside the css.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
    function date()
{
    var myDate = new Date();
    day = myDate.getDate();
    month = myDate.getMonth();
    year = myDate.getFullYear();

    var months = ["Ιανουαρίου", "Φεβρουαρίου","Μαρτίου", "Απριλίου", "Μαΐου", "Ιουνίου", "Ιουλίου", "Αυγούστου", "Σεπτεμβρίου", "Οκτωβρίου", "Νοεμβρίου","Δεκεμβρίου"];
    month = months[month];
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = day + " " + month + " " + year;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let state = document.querySelectorAll('.state');
  
  state.forEach(function(state_curr, i) {
  state_curr.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('pressed');
  })
  })
  }

/*function changestate()
{
    document.querySelector("#state").classList.toggle("pressed");
}*/

//Preventing content framing
/*window.onload=function()
{if(top!=window)top.location=window.location;}*/

//Preventing URL spoofing and polluting
var url = location.href;
var p = url.indexOf("?");
if (p >= 1)
{
  url = url.slice(0,p);
  self.location.replace(url);
}

//Preventing mail address harvesting
function display(id, name, domain, tld)
{
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = name + "" + "@" + "" + domain + "." + tld;
}
function send(name, domain, tld)
{
  location.href="mailto:" + name + "" + "@" + "" + domain + "." + tld;
}
```

```css
    body {
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #e3edf7;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, verdana;
}

.navbar-dark {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, purple, MidnightBlue);
  font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 17px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
}

.contact {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

#panel {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.elements > div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 22px;
  box-shadow: 15px 5px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -15px -5px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.elements > div i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.elements > div.pressed i {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.elements > div span.object {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.8);
  padding-left: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.elements > div span.object span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.5);
}

.elements:not(last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#temp {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.temperature {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 30px 30px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px -30px 30px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4),
    -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.temperature > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
}

.temperature > span > span.temp-data {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
}

.temperature > span > span.temp-data sup {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  top: 24%;
}

.temperature > span > span.temp-info {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6);
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.temperature:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 88%;
  height: 88%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.temperature:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 78%;
  height: 78%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>

    <title>Έξυπνο σπίτι</title>
  </head>

  <body onload="date()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-xl fixed-top">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><b> Έξυπνο σπίτι</b></span>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i> Χωλ</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./saloni.html"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i> Σαλόνι</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./diadromos.html"><i class="fas fa-shoe-prints"></i> Διάδρομος</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./domatio.html"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Δωμάτιο</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./kouzina.html"><i class="fas fa-sink"></i> Κουζίνα</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./toualeta.html"><i class="fas fa-toilet"></i> Τουαλέτα</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./krevatokamara.html"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Κρεβατοκάμαρα</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item contact">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./epikoinonia.html"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i> Επικοινωνία</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span id="date"></span>
      <div id="panel" class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div class="state">
              <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
              <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div class="state">
              <i class="fas fa-plug"></i>
              <span class="object"> Πρίζα </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div>
              <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>
              <span class="object">
                Ίντερνετ
                <span>20 mbps</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div>
              <i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
              <span class="object">
                Υγρασία
                <span>65%</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div>
              <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
              <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 elements">
            <div>
              <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
              <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="temp" class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span class="temperature">
              <span>
                <span class="temp-data"> 16 <sup>&deg;C</sup> </span>
                <span class="temp-info"> <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o"></i> Ψύξη </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could be related to css ordering. Check how css styling order works. `.elements > div.pressed` should be able to override `.elements > div` stylings.

Comment: It worked, i just had to add "i" too! Thanks! If i had div class="state" instead of div id="state" in my html? what should i change also so as to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define you toggle class `pressed` for `#state` in css.

Like this:

for `id="state"`:

```
#state.pressed {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
      -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

for `class="state"`:

```
.state.pressed {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
            -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

This is a reproducible example using `forEach()`. Namely, the currently clicked element is determined, and a class is assigned / removed to this element. Please note that I removed events `onclick="changestate()"` from class `state` from the html structure. It's a bad habit to write events inside tags in the html :)

```
window.onload = function() {
let state = document.querySelectorAll('.state');

  state.forEach(function(state_curr, i) {
      state_curr.addEventListener('click', function() {
       this.classList.toggle('pressed');
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You are right! That was what i missed! Thank you! If i had div class="state" instead of div id="state" in my html? what should i change also so as to work?

Comment: @user3378613, If this is a class, then you should replace `#` with `.`. I have updated my answer. Check, pls.

Comment: Correct! You help was very useful! i cleared up some things in my mind! One last thing i wanna solve is, in case i added one more <div class="state" onclick="changestate()">
              <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
              <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
            </div>   how would i make it click the one i want! i mean if clicking the second, to press the second! not the first

Comment: @user3378613, Do you want to click an event on `<i>` tag?

Comment: It's like having 3 buttons, and i want to push each and work! Now, whichever i push, it only pushes the first. But forget about buttons, it was just an example! Yes there is <i> in my code, you can see it in my html!

Comment: @user3378613, do you want a unique click event for each internal element? Where `state click = event 1`, `i click = event 2`. Right?

Comment: I changed the html code in the first post so as to understand what i mean! Have a look please! so i have two class "state". its two different buttons! Now in my code, when i click the second, it pushes the first and i click the first, it pushes the first. I want when i click the second to push the second!

Comment: @user3378613, Now I understand you.

Comment: @user3378613, What you want can be done with the `forEach()` method.

Comment: @user3378613, I made you a javascript code. Check, pls.

Comment: Hmm something is missing form html and thats why it doesnt work for me probably! Let me show you how it is in my html. There is a small difference

Comment: Sommthing i am doing wrong. Now it doesnt click at all and doesnt give any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226041/discussion-between-sergey-kuznetsov-and-user3378613).